# Passing function from object to React Native ListView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, native

I'm defining a function inside an object, and then passing it to a ListView.

However I'm having trouble getting the function to fire onPress. At the moment it's not doing anything when pressed.

```js
export default class Settings extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
        const listItems = [
            { title: 'Profile', icon: 'ios-contact', action: () => console.log('Profile') },
            { title: 'Log out', icon: 'ios-log-out', action: () => console.log('Log out') }
        ]
        this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(listItems) })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(item) => 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => item.action}>
                        <View>
                            <Ionicons name={item.icon} size={20} />
                            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
            />
        )
    }
};
```

I'm fairly new to React/JS, so I suspect it might be a syntax issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove fat arrow from TouchableOpacity onPress , like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={item.action}>
```

This will work.

**Edit:**
I created a project at snack. You can see that this approach fix your problem.

https://snack.expo.io/HJS68AjWN

Comment: This is initially what I thought also, but unfortunately it also doesn't do anything when pressed.

Comment: Your item.action already is a function. So you should use it without fat arrow. Also i copied your code to my demo project, and it worked. Please check other side of your code.

Comment: Ah yeah, you are correct, thank you! I had accidentally changed to this.action before removing the fat arrow. {item.action} works perfect :)